# Why the bundle id cannot be set?

Tags: ios, apple-developer, bundle-identifier

I am trying to set the bundle id in General -> Identifier, but the field is grey and cannot set anything...[image]

How can I do with it? Does that mean it is set by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you have multiple target schemes with different **Bundle Indentifier** values. You can set identifiers separately in **Signing & Capabilities** tab.